# Extend Hibernate's ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interpolation

I would like to extend this class: `org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator`

and override this method:

```
public String interpolate(String message, Context context, Locale locale) {
        ...
}
```

I've created `MyResourceBundleMessageInterpolator`:

```
public class MyResourceBundleMessageInterpolator extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator {

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String message, Context context, Locale locale) {
        return super.interpolate(message, context, locale);
    }
}
```

Also I know I have to register my message interpolator in `ValidatorFactory` object:

```
@Component
public class MyResourceBundleMessageInterpolatorConfigurer extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                                                      .configure()
                                                      .messageInterpolator(new MyResourceBundleMessageInterpolator())
                                                      .buildValidatorFactory();

    }
}
```

But the problem is I don't know what to do next. How can I tell Hibernate to use this `validatorFactory` object?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.2 + Spring 4.3.13

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the message interpolator in the `ValidatorFactory` object. The only next step is to overwrite the default `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` in a `@Configuration` class:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyValidationConfig
{
    @Bean
    public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean myValidatorFactory ()
    {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(messageInterpolator());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private static MessageInterpolator messageInterpolator ()
    {
        return new MyResourceBundleMessageInterpolator();
    }
}
```